# Unity SDK 7.1.0 + iOS "The redirect_uri URL must be absolute" on login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

After initialising, we call:

```
    List<string> l = new List<string>(){"public_profile", "email", "user_friends"};
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(l,onLoggedIn);
```

This opens up Facebook window on the phone but goes straight a page saying "The redirect_uri URL must be absolute".

On copying out the URL thats opened on iOS the redirect_uri section of the request looks like:

```
redirect_uri=fb2316571289234com.blueomega.horseacademy://authorize/
```

which doesn't mean much to me as it stands but I'm not sure where the error is.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version: v7.2.1 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity)?

Answer (score 0):

You may have specified a facebook URL Scheme Suffix in Unity. In the facebook settings tab located on your unity toolbar up top, delete the bundle identifier from the aforementioned field. PM me if you need help doing this, or this didn't help.

ALSO: the new facebook sdk's and IOS 9 have been problematic for a lot of people lately. The easiest solution for many is to build a web based login system that can be accessed by the new SFSafariViewController